# In Python, How can I remove some empty elements

Tags: python, list

there are some code:

```
[[u'\u725b\u8089\u6c64', ([], 0.5355934248407187)], [u'\u8272\u7cd5', (0.5336763336109008, [])]]
```

and I want to get following result:

```
[[u'\u725b\u8089\u6c64', 0.5355934248407187], [u'\u8272\u7cd5', 0.5336763336109008]]
```

Is there anyone knows how to deal with it?

Comment: Use a list comprehension

Comment: for i in final_simi:
        [[x,y] for x in i[0] for y in i[1] if y!='[]' ]?  but it do not get the final result

Comment: @JohnLaRooy  please show me the correcting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> L = [[u'\u725b\u8089\u6c64', ([], 0.5355934248407187)], [u'\u8272\u7cd5', (0.5336763336109008, [])]]
>>> [[x, y[0] if y[0] != [] else y[1]] for x, y in L]
[[u'\u725b\u8089\u6c64', 0.5355934248407187], [u'\u8272\u7cd5', 0.5336763336109008]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot~ for your help

Comment: sorry for disturb,  do you know if there are one input is:                              L = [[u'\u725b\u8089\u6c64', ([], 0.5355934248407187)], [u'\u8272\u7cd5', (0.5336763336109008, [])], [u'\u9999\u5377', ([], [])]]        how to geting the final result:                                                      list = [[u'\u725b\u8089\u6c64', 0.5355934248407187], [u'\u8272\u7cd5', 0.5336763336109008]]